# Message Queue service is not available

Tags: c#, tcp, cluster-computing, msmq

I have a TCP server, running as a Windows Service in a Windows Cluster. It receives messages and puts them into a queue (MSMQ). I have made a public MSMQ queue. And I get this error message:

```
System.Messaging.MessageQueueException (0x80004005): Message Queue service is not available.
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.MQCacheableInfo.get_WriteHandle()
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.StaleSafeSendMessage(MQPROPS properties, IntPtr transaction)
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.SendInternal(Object obj, MessageQueueTransaction internalTransaction, MessageQueueTransactionType transactionType)
```

I send messages to queue this way:

```
static void SendHelper(UncookedMessage uncooked)
{
    var msg = new Message(uncooked);
    msg.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new[] { typeof(UncookedMessage) });

    // (PER MESSAGE)
    msg.UseJournalQueue = false;
    msg.AttachSenderId = false;
    msg.Recoverable = true;

    SingleQueue.Send(msg);
}
```

The queue security gives full access to every user defined in the server and the cluster. My queue name is: **FormatName:DIRECT=OS:application9\uncooked_message_single**; but I have tested **application9\uncooked_message_single**, **application9.domain.com\uncooked_message_single** and **FormatName:DIRECT=OS:application9.domain.com\uncooked_message_single**. No one worked.

**Note:** This app was working perfectly with a private queue on a non-clustered server. I do not know much about windows clustering, but our admin says it's a failover cluster and it's on Windows Server 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message tells you that it cannot use the requested MSMQ service(s) I suggest checking if these are correctly set up.

Before going deeper into a cluster configuration I suggest that you...

- ... explicitly check the **access priviledges** of the queue on the **clustered server** (NOT on a single cluster *node*).
- ... check if there is a firewall blocking your messages in the network.

As you successfully tried your scenario in a non-clustered environment, there might obviously be differences in the clustered environment.

And indeed, setting up MSMQ on a clustered server requires a different configuration than on a non-clustered server.

Make sure that `MSMQ` service and the `Distributed Transaction Coordinator (DTC)` service are up and running on *each hardware node*.

In the **Failover Cluster Manager**, set up both MSMQ and DTC services as clustered resources, then configure MSMQ to be dependend on the clustered DTC as a "`dependendy`" Right click on `MSMQ -> Properties -> Dependencies`.

Do not forget to check your access priviledges again on the queue(s) you want to use on the *clustered server*. Setting up a queue on a single node does not work.

I do not know if this is mandatory in all cases, but on our Cluster we also have a file share configured as a dependcy for the MSMQ. To my understanding this should ensure that temporary files that are needed by MSMQ are still available after a node switch.

Additionally, here are two articles that I found very helpful in setting up the cluster nodes. They might be helpful in confirming step-by-step that your configurations are correct:

- "[Building MSMQ cluster](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mismail/archive/2007/04/18/building-an-msmq-cluster.aspx)". You will find several other links in that article that will guide you further.
- Microsoft also has a detailed document: "[Deploying Message Queuing (MSMQ) 3.0 in a Server Cluster](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=349D6584-9510-46F5-904E-2C58FA16EB85&displaylang=en&displaylang=en)".

Comment: Thanks; The problem was for using MSMQ from a clustered app, the MSMQ service should be clustered too and that needed a shared storage too and that needed a NAS. So for now we removed the clustered things and we are using a hand-made mechanism to decide which server should take responsibility.